# Crout Decomposition Parallel loop - Incorrect results

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, decomposition

I have a working sequential Crout Decomposition algorithm that I need to speed up if possible. I have looked online at various OpenMP methods of parallelising the algorithm and I can only get it to work correctly on the lower triangular matrix part of the code. The upper yields wrong results

I feel like I have been looking at the code too long and I may be blind to a data dependency that I am overlooking

Sequential code is as follows, which works correct

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        // Upper Triangle

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            q = matx[j * size + i];
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                q -= matx[j * size + k] * matx[k * size + i];
            }
            matx[j * size + i] = q;
        }

        // Lower Triangle

        for (j = i; j < size; j++)
        {
            q = matx[j * size + i];
            for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
            {
                q -= matx[j * size + k] * matx[k * size + i];
            }
            matx[j * size + i] = q;
        }
}
```

Now here is the code with the appropriate OpenMP directives

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        // Upper Triangle

#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k,q)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            q = matx[j * size + i];
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                q -= matx[j * size + k] * matx[k * size + i];
            }
            matx[j * size + i] = q;
        }

        // Lower Triangle

#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k,q)
        for (j = i; j < size; j++)
        {
            q = matx[j * size + i];
            for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
            {
                q -= matx[j * size + k] * matx[k * size + i];
            }
            matx[j * size + i] = q;
        }
}
```

If only the lower triangle is in parallel I yield the correct decompostion, however the upper throws out discrepancies

Many thanks for any help with this

Comment: Does [this](https://www.lume.ufrgs.br/bitstream/handle/10183/151001/001009773.pdf) help? I am not sure Cholesky-Crout algorithm is the same you intend to use.

Comment: That’s very good reading I must say! I will take a look to see if I can implement an alternative algorithm